# MySQL ALTER TABLE creating: 'Integrity constraint violation: 1452'

Tags: mysql, alter-table

The code below, when executed produces the following error:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

```
$db->executeUpdate('CREATE TABLE submission_statuses (name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
                    weight INT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(name)) ENGINE = InnoDB');
$db->executeUpdate('ALTER TABLE submissions ADD CONSTRAINT IDX_4 
                    FOREIGN KEY (status) REFERENCES submission_statuses(name)');
$db->executeUpdate('CREATE INDEX IDX_4 ON submissions (status)');
```

The tables both use the InnoDB engine.

Comment: This isn't related to the error, but you should know it's unnecessary to add the index for the foreign key column.  As of MySQL 4.1.2, creating a foreign key constraint automatically creates an index if one doesn't already exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The table `submissions` contains a value in the `status` column that does not exist in the newly created `submission_statuses` table. The `submission_statuses` table must be populated before the constraint is created.